# getline validation

Tags: c++, validation, matrix, getline

I need help from you about getline validation. I've created 2D Matrix using vector and I would like to fill that 2D Matrix with values from console.

The problem is with validation of the single values in input *(one row)*. When I type for example "d" or any other character, my code converts it to 0 and put the value in the matrix.. however thats not what I want. I want the user to type the values again *(until they are valid)* and put the new values in the matrix. This is the code:

```
string number, line;

cin.ignore();
double value = 0;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    while((getline(cin, number, '\n'))) {

        cout << "-> ";
        stringstream iss(number);

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if ( !(iss >> value) ) 
            {
                cout << "[ERROR] Invalid input. Type a valid number:" << endl;
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(256, '\n');
            } else {
                A[i][j] = value;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

**//Edit:**

What I want to accomplish is to check, if the value in the line which is inputted is a valid number. For example (input)

- 1 1 1 1
- 2 2 2 2
- 3 char 3 3
- [ERROR] Invalid input. Type a valid number:
- 3 3 3 3

And the output of that should be as it was inputted without the error line with random char other than number.

Right now with my code above, it says Invalid input, but it outputs the last line with error as 0 and the followed numbers after that 0 are zeroes too, because it ignores the new inputted fixed lines with valid numbers.

Output looks like this *(with the error)*:

- 1 1 1 1
- 2 2 2 2
- 3 0 0 0

Comment: where is n initialized for the for statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the values are *put* into the matrix with a value of `0`. Instead, they merely *stay* in the matrix with the value `0`! Essentially, you break out out of the `while`-loop processing lines independent on whether the values have been read successfully. I'd probably move some of the conditions around and avoid the intermediate stream: it doesn't seem helpful as you don't really do line-oriented input.

```
double value;
for (unsigned int i{0}; i != n && std::cin; ++i) {
    for (unsigned int j{0}; std::cin; ) {
        if (std::cin >> value) {
            A[i][j] = value;
            if (++j == n) {
                ++i;
                break;
        }
        else if (!std::cin.eof()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::string line;
            std::getline(std::cin, line); // !std::cin.eof() => this shall be successful!
            std::cout << "ERROR invalid number input: ignoring '" << line << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply :) I've edited the post, please look at it. I've explained in the detail what I want to accomplish. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ManPay: I don't have a setup accessible right now to test it, but mostly my code does just that. The output in case of an error is a bit more helpful than you asked for and it would read a partial line. That's easily fixed by just resetting the index in the row, though.

Comment: @Kuhl I just found out, that when I for example write this : 1 1 1 F and then it couts 'ignoring " F" ' that when I want to replace it with a new number, I can type a lot of numbers like 1 1 1 1 1 1 and it will replace the "F", but also it will fill the rest of the lines... I'm not sure how to make it, so it will replace only "F" and it wont fill the rest of it, after I hit enter.... I need to find out how to ignore the rest of input numbers after that. Otherwise its working good...

Comment: @ManPay: my code kept the index within the row, actually quite deliberately. You can just reset the index witin row to have the already successfully read value overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the getline out of the while to make it works.

Here an example. I didn't compiled it but it should give you a general idea.

```
// To be tested
string number, line;

cin.ignore();
double value = 0;
bool validInput;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    validInput = false;

    while(!validInput) {
        getline(cin, number, '\n');

        std::istringstream iss(number);
        iss >> value;

        if (!iss.fail() && iss.eof())
        {
            cout << "[ERROR] Invalid input. Type a valid number:" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(256, '\n');
            continue;
        }

        validInput = true;

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
}
```